# How can i stop the program from skipping my check the second time around?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am creating a program to take in sets of binary digits and convert them into hammingcodes (Effectively take in 8 digits, turn into 12, print out) but i am having trouble. Currently, i am using a JTextField for the user to enter their number, then they press a JButton to enter the data. I then do funky shit with that number to put it into a list and confirm that this is the last of the numbers they wish to enter. If they click a JButton called yes (New text in button, but same button) if goes on to do what i need. But if they click the other JButton called no, it goes back and repeats the same process. My problem is after clicking no once, the program stops allowing you to press no at the step to check if you want to add another list of numbers. IT appears to skip the check all together and assume they pressed yes as it does the rest of the working out thats done after all entry is finished.

My code is a tad messy due to messing with it for a few hours.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MainProgram extends JFrame
{
public MainProgram()
    {
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    MainProgram mp = new MainProgram();
    mp.run();
    }

private void run()
    {
    java.util.List<Integer> streamSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    java.util.List<Integer> tempEight = new ArrayList<>();
    java.util.List<Integer> finalStream = new ArrayList<>();
    yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            checkYes = true;
            }
        });
    no.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            checkNo = true;
            }
        });
    init();
    yesChange("Enter");
    boolean confirm = false;
    int aCheck = 0;
    while (aCheck == 0)
        {
        confirm = false;
        while (!confirm)
            {
            setTopText("<html>Please enter your next 8 bits. Do not enter more than 8 bits.<br> Press Enter when done</html>");
            yesChange("Enter");
            confirm =  checkYes();
            }
        confirm = false;
        setTopText("Digits Successfully added.");
        int stream =  checkInput();
        do
            {
            streamSplit.add(stream % 10);
            stream /= 10;
            } while (stream != 0);
        setYesNo();
        setTopText("<html>Are you finished entering streams?</html>");
        yesChange("YES");
        noChange("NO");
        aCheck = 2;
        checkYes();
        checkNo();
        while (aCheck == 2)
            {
            if ( checkNo())
                {
                aCheck = 0;
                System.out.println("CrapNo");
                }
            else if (checkYes())
                {
                aCheck = 1;
                System.out.println("CrapYes");
                }
            }
        }




    int arrayLength = streamSplit.size();
    int bufferLength = 8 - arrayLength % 8;
    int numberOfStreams = 0;
    if (bufferLength != 8)
        {
        numberOfStreams = arrayLength / 8 + 1;
        } else
        {
        numberOfStreams = arrayLength / 8;
        }
    int tempStreams = numberOfStreams;
    System.out.println(numberOfStreams + "<Streams Buffer>" + bufferLength);
    while (bufferLength > 0 && bufferLength != 8)
        {
        streamSplit.add(0);
        bufferLength--;
        }
    while (tempStreams > 0)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
            tempEight.add(streamSplit.get(i));
            }
        if ((tempEight.get(0) + tempEight.get(1) + tempEight.get(3) + tempEight.get(4) + tempEight.get(6)) % 2 == 0)
            {
            tempEight.add(0, 0);
            } else
            {
            tempEight.add(0, 1);
            }
        if ((tempEight.get(1) + tempEight.get(3) + tempEight.get(5) + tempEight.get(6) + tempEight.get(7)) % 2 == 0)
            {
            tempEight.add(1, 0);
            } else
            {
            tempEight.add(1, 1);
            }
        if ((tempEight.get(3) + tempEight.get(4) + tempEight.get(5) + tempEight.get(8) + tempEight.get(9)) % 2 == 0)
            {
            tempEight.add(3, 0);
            } else
            {
            tempEight.add(3, 1);
            }
        if ((tempEight.get(7) + tempEight.get(8) + tempEight.get(9) + tempEight.get(10)) % 2 == 0)
            {
            tempEight.add(7, 0);
            } else
            {
            tempEight.add(7, 1);
            }
        tempStreams--;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
            finalStream.add(tempEight.get(0));
            tempEight.remove(0);
            }
        }

    Collections.reverse(streamSplit);
    System.out.print("Your original bit-stream was: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStreams * 2; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
            System.out.print(streamSplit.get(j + (i * 4)));
            }
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your new HammingCode bit-stream is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStreams * 3; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
            System.out.print(finalStream.get(j + (i * 4)));
            }
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }


public Boolean checkYes = false;
public Boolean checkNo = false;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Absolute Layout Example");
private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
private JLabel topText = new JLabel("Welcome to my Hamming Code Generator", JLabel.CENTER);
private JTextField inputText = new JTextField();
private JButton yes = new JButton("YES");
private JButton no = new JButton("NO");

public void init()
    {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    topText.setLocation(0, 0);
    topText.setSize(400, 50);
    topText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    inputText.setLocation(0,50);
    inputText.setSize(400,75);
    inputText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    yes.setSize(80, 40);
    yes.setLocation(60, 135);

    no.setSize(80, 40);
    no.setLocation(260, 135);

    contentPane.add(topText);
    contentPane.add(inputText);
    contentPane.add(yes);
    contentPane.add(no);

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    frame.setSize(400, 225);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public void setTopText(String s)
    {
    topText.setText(s);
    }

public void setYesNo()
    {
    checkYes = false;
    checkNo = false;
    }

public Boolean checkYes() {return checkYes;}

public Boolean checkNo() {return checkNo;}

public int checkInput()
    {
    String temp1 = inputText.getText();
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(temp1);
    return temp;
    }

public void yesChange(String s)
    {
    yes.setText(s);
    }

public void noChange(String s)
    {
    no.setText(s);
    }


}
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to shoehorn linear running console code, especially the `while (true)` loop, into an event-driven Swing GUI, and that simply won't work. You will want to re-code it as an event-driven program.

Comment: Regarding, `"My code is a tad messy due to messing with it for a few hours."` -- Please remember that we're volunteers helping out, and it would be greatly appreciated if you would clean up any messiness before posting code here. You will want to make it as easy as possible for others to be able to help you. As for me, I have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I tried to explain what the code does in the paragraph prior to the code post. Yeah, shoehorning is probably the right term. I will attempt to rewrite the code as an event-driven program. Thanks for the help

Comment: All I know is that you're trying to change the state of the GUI -- and this includes the text in the JButtons, the text in the JLabel, and the behaviors of the JButton presses -- as the program is running. This would be done by creating a program that is aware of its state -- the state of key fields, and that changes its behaviors and its display depending on this state. Also your while loops will effectively lock up your GUI preventing it from responding since they risk typing up the GUI's event thread.

Comment: Regarding `"I tried to explain what the code does in the paragraph prior to the code post."` -- please understand that you've posted a lot of code to including a **huge** uncommented `run()` method. I'm not sure that your explanation is up to snuff given the size of your code.

Comment: Also, as a "side" recommendation, one unrelated to your main problem, understand that null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it tough to answer this question not fully knowing what your code is doing, especially the part where you `"... do funky #### with that number..."`

But I do know that you have significant issues with your program structure, especially within your lengthy `run()` method where you have numerous nested `while (...)` loops and `do-while` loops, code constructs that might seem at home within a linear processing console program but which seems out of place within an event-driven Swing GUI.

What I suggest that you do is try to use some state-dependent coding. For instance, you could give your class the boolean variables, enteringData and dataValidYet, to represent two key states: whether the user is now entering data into the JTextField, and whether that data has yet been validated yet. And then within your JButton ActionListeners, use if and if/else blocks to decide what to do on button push depending on the state of these boolean fields, and likely other key fields of the class.

For a code "skeleton" example, one that doesn't yet do anything, but hopefully will show you the structure I'm talking about:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StateMachine extends JPanel {
    private static final String INITIAL_TITLE = "Please enter your next 8 bits. "
            + "Do not enter more than 8 bits.\n"
            + "Press Enter when done";
    private static final String ARE_YOU_FINISHED = "Are you finished entering streams?";
    private static final String YES = "Yes";
    private static final String ENTER = "Enter";
    private static final String NO = "No";
    private static int GAP = 8;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 30;

    // this is a JTextArea built to look like a JLabel
    private JTextArea topTextArea = new JTextArea(2, COLUMNS);
    private JTextField dataEntryField = new JTextField(COLUMNS);
    private JButton yesEnterButton = new JButton(ENTER);
    private JButton noButton = new JButton(NO);
    private boolean enteringData = true;
    private boolean dataValidYet = false;

    public StateMachine() {
        yesEnterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                yesEnterButtonActionPerfromed(e);
            }
        });

        noButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                noButtonActionPerfromed(e);
            }
        });

        topTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        topTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        topTextArea.setFocusable(false);
        topTextArea.setEditable(false);
        topTextArea.setOpaque(false);
        topTextArea.setText(INITIAL_TITLE);

        JPanel innerButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP, 0));
        innerButtonPanel.add(yesEnterButton);
        innerButtonPanel.add(noButton);
        JPanel outerButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        outerButtonPanel.add(innerButtonPanel);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(topTextArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(dataEntryField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(outerButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    protected void noButtonActionPerfromed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO depending on state of enteringData and dataValidYet booleans
        // change text in buttons, do things with JTextField data
        // set state of enteringData and dataValidYet booleans

        if (enteringData) {
            // a no press is meaningless if entering data
            return;
        }

        // .... more

    }

    private void yesEnterButtonActionPerfromed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO depending on state of enteringData and dataValidYet booleans
        // change text in buttons, do things with JTextField data
        // set state of enteringData and dataValidYet booleans

        if (enteringData) {
            topTextArea.setText(ARE_YOU_FINISHED);
            yesEnterButton.setText(YES);
            yesEnterButton.setActionCommand(YES);
            enteringData = false;
            return;
        }
        // .... more

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        StateMachine mainPanel = new StateMachine();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("State Machine");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, as a "side" recommendation, one unrelated to your main problem, understand that null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Note that if this were my program, I would use more indirection including creating separate classes to separate out the GUI portion of the program from the logic portion.

Comment: I originally had the GUI portions seperated into a different class, i should have reverted my code back to that state before posting it but thank you for the help. I will mark this solved and attempt to rewrite the code like this. Hopefully i wont run into issues but if i do im sure you will see my post. Thanks mate.